# How do I run GWT on a linux server

Tags: gwt

Sorry for this simple question but I seem not to find any other way than to publish a GWT app to Google App Spot. I'm sure there must be a way to do this.

I've got the development environment working on my local machine but I'd like to publish the solution to my ubuntu server running nginx.

Edit: Just thought of something... maybe I can just deploy the js-code to the ubuntu server? As simple as that? ;)

Comment: The question is about deploying GWT in your Ubuntu Server or in Google App Engine? (or maybe both)

Comment: "any other way than to publish a GWT app to Google AppSpot." :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant just deploy the js-code and html files to an ubuntu server and put it for apache to serve, well... unless your code only outputs hello world that is. Probably your GWT app is calling/using some other Java code that needs to be deployed in tomcat or jboss, is it? If that is the case, ie your GWT is in a war, then yes, just deploy that .war file to any container on any linux box.

Try to copy your .war into a jboss deploy dir.

Deploying to app spot is similar, ie uploading your .war to google. Read more here http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideDeploying.html

Comment: Got it. Now on the other hand I'm only after GWT for the RIA stuff. Not server stuff at all. I already have all that set up and running in node. I still have to publish a .war?

Comment: GWT isnt really made to by only client-side RIA, I think it would be quite difficult to do that. If you want to make client-side only apps, look into Backbone.js. Now, you could still attempt to serve your GWT app with only a normal http server such as nginx.

Comment: To do that, you would take your generated "module" where all the html+javacript+css files are and put them under apache or nginx, then visit the index.html or other entrypoint you defined for your gwt app.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. [Run it in Eclipse](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/usingeclipse.html#running)
2. [Run it with Ant](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html#run)